# how can i delay UI update until after calculations are finished?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

my c# winforms program has one tabcontrol with a few tabs displaying listviews, labels, buttons etc. the tabpages are not shown on load. the code simplified looks like this:

```
public main()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    removeTabPages(); //removes all but one; deleting this line doesn't change anything
    main_tabcontrol.SelectedIndex = 0; //doesn't change anything no matter where i put it
    loadData();
    doSomeCalculations();
    addTabPages();
    main_tabcontrol.SelectedIndex = 2; //same issue if i pick any other tab here
}

private void Tabs_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateDataInTab();   
}
```

this loads some data, does some calculations and then switches to tabpage 2. i would expect to see the data processed by the loadData() and doSomeCalculations() functions displayed. instead it displays the default values (mostly nothing) until i switch to another tab and then back. that also verifies Tabs_SelectedIndexChanged() works as intended.

i'd like to understand why this happens and how i can make it work as planned.

running loadData() and doSomeCalculations() as async tasks, and awaiting them, does solve this, but it opens so many other problems that i'd like to avoid it (i don't need this async). since my issue is the exact opposite (i need the code to run synchronous), this shouldn't be the solution anyways.

Comment: Are you using any kind of databinding?

Comment: @letsdance: Sounds like your methods are already async; is that right?

Comment: i'm not using databinding. the methods are not async.

Comment: actually i'm using some sort of databinding, but i think it's not relevant because i'm just using it as a different way to fill the DGV programatically: 
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
fill_dt(); 
DataGridView dgv; 
dgv.DataSource = dt; 

on startup the application loads the data from files to variables (classes) and then adds it to the controls programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have it in your constructor, the best place to put it is on the load:

```
private void main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    main_tabcontrol.SelectedIndex = 0; 
    loadData();
    doSomeCalculations();
    main_tabcontrol.SelectedIndex = 2; 
}
```

Comment: it seems that main_Load does not fire at all. i moved the code there, and a MessageBox.Show. codes does not get executed and no box is shown.

Comment: activated load event in the designer and now it works! thx =)

Answer (score 0):

1. Never do anything beside the actual initialization in constructor
2. Use Loaded event to implement initial work
3. Avoid calculations and other CPU heavy work in UI thread. Use the backgroung thread to do this. Use async/await

To use Load Event double click empty space on the form or use Properties Explorer and switch to events.

Comment: i cannot find a Loaded event. can you give an example how to do this? the calculations are not CPU heavy and since i want them to be finished before anything else happens, there is no reason to make them async. they do not freeze the UI for a noticeable time.

Comment: Added info on how to use Loaded event (Load event in WinForms). Again IMO what you are doing is wrong. You made an assumption that noone will ever modify these methods and there is no possibility for them to be resource cosuming. You should always keep in mind that any piece of code should be reusable

Comment: if they become resource consuming i can still make them async. as i wrote in my initial post i actually did it (and kept this code in case i need it later). but i ran into other troubles and for now it's more efficient to do it straight. these other troubles might have been related to the same problem (putting it in constructor instead of load), but at the moment there is no reason to make it async. the primary goal is to get something working and finished, i can still improve it later.